# Should I write "for which I am interested" or "in which I am interested"?

Tags: prepositions

Do we have to write "it is a field **for which** I am interested" or "it is a field **in which** I am interested".

Answer (score 1):

The typical wording for interests is: "I am interested in something." So the correct wording for your example is:

"It is a field in which I am interested."

Comment: Can we also say : "It is a field which i am interested in." ?

Comment: I say yes. Some authorities say not to end sentences with prepositions, but that is considered pedantic and archaic by many.

Comment: I would also drop the "which" in the simpler construction: "It is a field I am interested in" or "It is a field that interests me."